# Dialog Box not topmost while owner docked app bar is topmost

Tags: c#, wpf, modal-dialog, topmost

I have a docked app bar and when you log out, a modal login dialog box is shown. What I really want is to click on the app bar and have the login box become activated. To do this, I made the app bar the owner of the login dialog box. However, I want the docked app bar to always be topmost, but the login box to not be topmost. Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I want behavior like this, I make the dialog topmost, but then once it has loaded I remove the topmost.  That way the dialog floats to the front, but then, the topmost behavior is gone so it can be moved to the back as desired.  If you do this you should be able to remove the parent association you made.

Comment: Thanks! However, with the parent association removed, do you know of a way for the dialog box to come to the front when the app bar is clicked? I'm assuming there's some event raising, but I can't get that to work since the app bar is disabled/inactive/unclickable (I don't know the technical word). Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I figured out a work around... by making it modeless and changing the IsHitTestVisible property. Thanks for your input!